# Create an iterator with a next method that returns each value of the array when .next is called

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, iterator, closures

I am trying to implement an iterator function that is basically just a closure in JS.

I have been able to list out each value of the array by calling `iteratorWithNext()`, but I am confused on how to implement a function next

Below is what I have come up with, but I am getting a `TypeError: iteratorWithNext.next is not a function` when I call `iteratorWithNext()`

```
function nextIterator(arr) {
    let count = 0
    function next(){return count++}
    return next
}

const array3 = [1, 2, 3];
const iteratorWithNext = nextIterator(array3);
```

Below is the desired output:

```
console.log(iteratorWithNext.next()); // -> should log 1
console.log(iteratorWithNext.next()); // -> should log 2
console.log(iteratorWithNext.next()) // -> should log 3
```

Comment: the iterator needs `.value` to get the value. do you want your own (different) style?

Comment: (To point out the difference in the answer specifically: `return next`, return the function, becomes `return { next }`, return an object with a `next` property that is the function.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return an object literal with the `next` method:

```js
function nextIterator(arr) {
  let count = 0

  function next() {
    return arr[count++]
  }
  
  // return an object literal with the next method
  return {
    next
  }
}

const array3 = [1, 2, 3];
const iteratorWithNext = nextIterator(array3);

console.log(iteratorWithNext.next()); // -> should log 1
console.log(iteratorWithNext.next()); // -> should log 2
console.log(iteratorWithNext.next()) // -> should log 3
```

Comment: I forgot to include the parameter arr for the function nextIterator and argument array3 for the calling of nextIterator(). What happened to the const array3? How come you didn't use array3 for the parameter for nextIterator?

Comment: See updated answer. Note that this doesn't follow the standard JS iterator protocol (you need to return an object { value: any, done: bool }.